AxisValueLabel with orientation vertical/verticalReversed is not working with padding SwiftUI Charts
I am trying to apply padding on AxisValueLabel Text with orientation: .horizontal but it's working properly but it is impacting on for orientation vertical/verticalReversed. Result is showing with stretched value with vertical.
struct Workout: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let day: String
    let minutes: Int
}

extension Workout {
    static let walkWorkout: [Workout] = [
        .init(day: NSLocalizedString("mon", comment: ""), minutes: 23),
        .init(day: "Tue", minutes: 35),
        .init(day: "Wed", minutes: 55),
        .init(day: "Thu", minutes: 30),
        .init(day: "Fri", minutes: 15),
        .init(day: "Sat", minutes: 65),
        .init(day: "Sun", minutes: 81),
    ]
    
    static let runWorkout: [Workout] = [
        .init(day: NSLocalizedString("mon", comment: ""), minutes: 16),
        .init(day: "Tue", minutes: 12),
        .init(day: "Wed", minutes: 55),
        .init(day: "Thu", minutes: 34),
        .init(day: "Fri", minutes: 22),
        .init(day: "Sat", minutes: 43),
        .init(day: "Sun", minutes: 90),
    ]
}

import Charts
import SwiftUI

struct YAxisVerticalLabel: View {
    @State private var isCentered = true
    let workoutData = [
        (workoutType: "Walk", data: Workout.walkWorkout),
        (workoutType: "Run", data: Workout.runWorkout)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart {
                ForEach(workoutData, id: \.workoutType) { element in
                    ForEach(element.data) {
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Day", $0.day),
                            y: .value("Workout(in minutes)", $0.minutes)
                        )
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Workout(type)", element.workoutType))
                    .position(by: .value("Workout(type)", element.workoutType))
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(position: .leading) {
                    axis in
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisValueLabel(
                        centered: isCentered,
                        orientation: isCentered ? .verticalReversed : .horizontal
                    ) {
                        if isCentered { // When in between the grid
                            Text("\(axis.index * 25)s")
                                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        } else { // When at the grid - in this case only I want to set a padding to move label some pixel above to make it align with grid line, without padding it's showing at grid as centered
                            Text("\(axis.index * 25)s")
                                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                .padding(.bottom, 8) // Applied padding on label in case of horizontal
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Case 1: isCentered false - I am getting result without padding in horizontal as below -

Case 2: isCentered false - When I am applying padding (.padding(.bottom, 8)), horizontal label is moving above as per padding as below -

Case 3: isCentered true - When I am applying padding (.padding(.bottom, 8)), text is getting stretched and also moving towards left from dotted vertical line as below -

I just want to apply a padding to move text upward with some pixels. in case of isCentered false (horizontal)
I want to achieve 2 scenarios as -

horizontal label with some pixel above as bottom aligned with grid
line
vertical label in center of grid

Note: I also noticed when I am putting if condition also vertical label is getting stretched without padding applied on horizontal label case.
Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Why centered: true if you don’t want the text to be centered? Can you show the desired result using an image?

Hi @Sweeper, I have updated my scenario as per horizontal and vertical cases. thanks for raising query.

Rather than using padding, try using more parameters that are provided by the AxisValueLabel. The anchor can be used to move the labels above the grid line and the horizontalSpacing & verticalSpacing can be used to adjust the labels' positions along the dotted line.
For example:
.chartYAxis(content: {
    AxisMarks(position: .leading) { value in
        AxisGridLine()
            AxisValueLabel (
                anchor: isCentered ? nil : .bottomTrailing,
                orientation: isCentered ? .verticalReversed : .horizontal,
                horizontalSpacing: 0,
                verticalSpacing: isCentered ? 0 : -3) {
                    Text("\(value.index * 25)s")
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
        }
    }
})

Chart when isCentered equals true:

Chart when isCentered equals false:

The Charts framework drops the top horizontal label in this situation. To adjust for that, the y values can be entered manually and should include one additional value:
AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: [0,25,50,75,100,125]) { value in

The update looks like this:

